# How to get implicit related records in a table with SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, implicit

Assume that I have records like this:

```
|    id   |  equivalent_id  |
+---------+-----------------+
|----11---|--------22-------|
|----22---|--------33-------|
|----33---|--------44-------|
|----44---|--------55-------|
|----55---|--------66-------|
```

I want to write a query in Oracle to get implicit relation between records. for example if I pass in `11` as in input to the query, it should return `22, 33, 44, 55, 66`.

Because `11` -> `22` and `22` -> `33`, then we can conclude that `11` -> `33` and so on.

**UPDATE**

The numbers can be outside of above range, for example numbers can be in `1` to `99999999` and doesn't exist any mathematical relation between records.

Comment: I want to select rows from table

Comment: if I pass in 11 as in input to the query, it should return 22, 33, 44, 55, 66.

Comment: Yes, and because i can acheive from 11 to 33 and others with transitivity principle

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT equivalent_id
  FROM <nameyourtable>
START WITH ID=11
CONNECT BY PRIOR equivalent_id=id;
```

Don't know, if I got this pseudo-code right, but you get the picture ...

Comment: Your start with and connect by clauses are switched

Comment: Thanks for your reply, l'm completely familiar with `connect by prior` queries, but i think it doesn't work for this case.

Comment: Why, thought you want all equivalent IDs for a given ID? This query returns exactly what you want: 22,33,44,55,66  - just tried it :-)

Comment: @sers, yes, but connect by prior doesn't help here

Comment: Why wouldn't it? At least it exactly returns the values you want! Maybe your example is too simplistic?